# Unable to load ResourceBundle with ResourceBundle.getBundle() Can't find bundle for base name , locale en_US

Tags: java, javafx-8, maven-3, resourcebundle, fxmlloader

I see the following exception when I try to load a properties file:

```
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name /fontawesome/fontawesome, locale en_US
```

I'm using a maven project and my properties file is located at `src\main\resources\fontawesome\fontawesome.properties`

I'm using the below code to load this file from JavaFX8 main class:

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
fxmlLoader.setResources(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/fontawesome/fontawesome.properties"));
```

Trying the absolute path fails, as does renaming the file to `fontawesome_en_US.properties` or `fontawesome_en.properties` (as suggested in other SO posts).

Comment: FYI the reason why adding locale suffix e.g. `en` or `_en_US` is unnecessary/doesn't fix your problem is because [`ResourceBundle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) will use the file with no suffix as the default if it can't one with a matching suffix. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48185438/885922) explains why absolute path doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had to include `.properties` files in the `pom.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.fxml</include>
            <include>**/*.css</include>
            <include>**/*.properties</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Comment: As https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html said, no need to define like this because maven will look for the resources under the default folder.

Answer (score 0):

Do not include the .properties extension.

The ResourceBundle try to load the properties file from the current classpath.

If the properties are stored in subdirectory , use "." instead of "/".

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("fontawesome.fontawesome")
```

Comment: I tried , but I still see the error, i itried both, with .properties amd without the .properties. `FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
  fxmlLoader.setResources(ResourceBundle.getBundle("fontawesome.fontawesome"));`                                                                    `Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name fontawesome.fontawesome, locale' en_US'

Answer (score 0):

Your language properties file should end with **_en**, so in your case `fontawesome_en.properties` and you should load it with `ResourceBundle.getBundle("fontawesome.fontawesome")`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my experience:
If you put a "." in the name then the ResourceBundle.getBundle() will look for a class instead of properties file. That class will look something like this:

import java.util.ListResourceBundle;

```
public class DataEncryptionStrings extends ListResourceBundle {
@Override
protected Object[][] getContents() {
    return new Object[][] {
        {"ErrorCreateKeystoreInstance", "an exception occurred creating the keystore instance"},
        {"ErrorLoadInitialKeystore", "an exception occurred loading the initial keystore"},
        {"ErrorLoadKeystore", "an exception occurred loading the keystore"},
```

It follows the naming convention:
{classname}.class is the default class
{classname}_en_US.class is english US class
{classname}_fr_FR.class in the french class

if you don't have any "." in the name but have a "/" in it, then it'll look for property files instead.
If you don't have either a "." of "/" in the name, I think either property files or ListResourceBundle can be made available. It'll find whatever you've provided.  I'm not sure though if that behavior is same for all VMs.
The problem I had that got me interested in searching for a solution was that I had a filename with "."'s in it.  I'm pretty sure that my problem was that I implement properties file and not ListResourceBundle classes, and with a file name containing a "." in it, ResourceBundle.getBundle(name) looked for ListResourceBundle classes.   When I replaced the "." in the filename with a "_", I was then able to find the default ResourceBundle properties file.

User68883 seems to be using an absolute address "/fontawesome/fontawesome.properties" instead of a relative address "fontawesome/fontawesome.properties". Also, on the ResourceBundle.getBundle, never include the files extension in the name nor the Locale.  That's what ResouceBundle automagically does for you as it goes through a resolution process to get the best resource you have in the resource directory for the devices Locale.