# Can't find resource bundle exception

Tags: java, properties, resources, resourcebundle

I want to use a resource bundle called `strings` but I get following error when running my main method in `MainApplication.java`:

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name strings, locale de_DE
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:845)
    at logic.MainApplication.start(MainApplication.java:20) (...)
```

My project structure:

[image: project structure]

The two files `strings.properties` and `strings_de_DE.properties` are stored in the same directory as `MainApplication.java` and all three files are in the directory `pi_display/src/logic/` (IntelliJ puts them into a virtual "Resource Bundle" directory for a clearer display of the project structure).

Main class/method:

```
public class MainApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locale locale = Locale.GERMANY;
        ResourceBundle resources = ResourceBundle.getBundle("strings", locale);
        // ...
    }
```

I've already tried to move the files to other packages and specify the `baseName` of the bundle (i.e. `logic.strings` or other package structures if I moved them elsewhere).

I don't understand why the bundle can't be found given `MainApplication` and the bundle files are in the same directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably using wrong `baseName` for your bundle. According to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-):

> Gets a resource bundle using the specified base name, the default
> locale, and the caller's class loader

"Class loader" means that resource loaded from folder with compiled classes. In the screenshot, the path to your resource is `src/logic/strings.properties`, so it should be located in `classes/logic/` folder, and as baseName you should use `logic/strings` (or `logic/strings.properties`, I'm not sure about that).

Comment: This worked, thank you! As you said my mistake was that the resource bundle was not added to the output directory of my (compiled) project. Regarding your last sentence: `logic/strings` or `logic.strings` works, `logic/strings.properties` does not.

Comment: How did you manage to get the resource bundle to the output directory? I have the same problem. The properties files are not in the jar file in classes/packagename/